# Cannot filter out LogEvents using MinimumLevel.Override?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog, serilog-filter

I have the following serilog config' code:

```cs
            loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .MinimumLevel.Is(GetLoggingLevel(configuration.GetSection($"{Constants.LoggingSectionName}:MinimumLevel")))
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: Constants.Template,
                                 theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                                 levelSwitch: HasLevelSwitches(configuration)
                                                ? new Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch(GetLoggingLevel(GetDictionaryOfSettings(configuration, "LevelSwitches")["$consoleLogLevel"]))
                                                : null)
                .WriteTo.File(path: configuration.GetSection($"{Constants.LoggingSectionName}:FilePath").Value,
                            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                            retainedFileCountLimit: GetIntSafe(configuration.GetSection($"{Constants.LoggingSectionName}:RetainedFileCountLimit"), 31),
                            shared: true,
                            outputTemplate: Constants.Template,
                            fileSizeLimitBytes: ConvertMegaBytesToBytesSafe(configuration.GetSection($"{Constants.LoggingSectionName}:FileSizeLimitMegaBytes"), 500L),
                            rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                            flushToDiskInterval: GetTimeSpanFromSecondsSafe(configuration.GetSection($"{Constants.LoggingSectionName}:FlushToDiskIntervalSeconds")),
                            levelSwitch: HasLevelSwitches(configuration)
                                                ? new Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch(GetLoggingLevel(GetDictionaryOfSettings(configuration, "LevelSwitches")["$fileLogLevel"]))
                                                : null);
```

As you can see see, I have hard code some SourceContext namespaces.

My minimum log level is set to: `Information`

At Runtime, I consistently see log events generated from the two namespaces I have stated I would like filtering out less they be at LogLevel:Warning.

##### Update 1

I have tried very granular or loose and I have the same issue:

```
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

##### Reserch

[How can I override Serilog levels differently for different sinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341787/how-can-i-override-serilog-levels-differently-for-different-sinks)

Comment: Can you include the log configuration section of `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @RobertoFerraris - its just a custom dictionary of settings - the goal here is to config serilog in c# and then toggle simple stuff using a custom settings block in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue using:

```
loggerConfiguration.Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent =>
            logEvent.Level < LogEventLevel.Warning &&
            Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.AspNetCore").Invoke(logEvent)
```

and stopped using:

`.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)`